# Prove that if $ \lim_{x\to\infty}f\left(x\right)=L $ then $ \lim_{n\to\infty}\intop_{0}^{1}f\left(n\cdot x\right)dx=L $.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, riemann-integration

let $ f $ be integrable function in any interval such [0,M].
assume $ \lim_{x\to\infty}f\left(x\right)=L $ for some $ L\in \mathbb{R} $

and prove that

$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\intop_{0}^{1}f\left(n\cdot x\right)dx=L $.

I've managed to prove that

$ \intop_{0}^{1}f\left(n\cdot x\right)dx=\frac{1}{n}\intop_{0}^{n}f\left(x\right)dx $ .

Im not sure how to continue. Thanks in advance

Comment: For an intuitive understanding, $\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n f(x) dx$ is the average value of $f(x)$ from $0$ to $n$. As $n$ approaches $\infty$, the average value will approach $L$ because "most" of the interval from $0$ to $n$ will approach $L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\epsilon >0$, take $N >0$ such that $\vert f(x) - L \vert < \epsilon$ for $x >N$

Then for $n >N$ $$\begin{aligned}\left\vert \frac{1}{n}\intop_{0}^{n}f(x)dx - L \right\vert &= \left\vert\frac{1}{n} \intop_0^N f(x) \ dx + \frac{1}{n} \intop_N^n \left(f(x)-L\right) \ dx + \frac{n-N}{n} L - L\right\vert \\
&\le \frac{1}{n} \intop_0^N \vert f(x) \vert \ dx + \epsilon \frac{n - N}{n} + \frac{N}{n} \vert L \vert
\end{aligned}$$

As $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$, and $\int_0^N \vert f(x) \vert \ dx$ is finite by hypothesis, you can bound the RHS of the inequality by $3 \epsilon$ for $n$ large enough which provides the desired conclusion.